# Does Assignment before return have a cost in python?

Tags: python, optimization

Given 2 similar python functions:

```
def get_text(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
       text = pickle.load(f)
    return text
```

and

```
def get_text2(filename):
     with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
         return pickle.load(f)
```

Would there be any performance difference betwen `get_text` and `get_text2` ?   Or will the python interpreter still have to do an assignment under the covers before returning?

This question is mostly about the assignment to a local variable before return -- the unpickling a file part is just a convenient example I had handy.

Comment: Probably, yes. [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) indicates extra instructions (`store_fast`, `load_fast`) are required. But I doubt it's a bottleneck compared to actually reading the file.

Comment: I'm not sure if the interpreter is even allowed to optimize that away. Theoretically you could inspect the call stack and check if `text` exists as a local variable in `get_text`.

Comment: Why ask us?  You have the ultimate authority in front of you.  Use the `timeit` module to run empirical tests.

Comment: Usually we don't worry about assignment times.  That's just some pointer manipulation.  Now new objects are created or copied. I would put the return outside the with context,

Comment: Hey thanks for the great comments -  @Prune I asked because I thought someone in the community would know and didn't know about the `dis` function to find out the instructions. And as for not worrying about assignment times, I agree but the question came up and I was curious.  Maybe it makes a small difference for large files or a large quantity of files.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for mentioning that I could `dis` this which I think provides the answer:

This done with python 3.7.1

```
>>> def get_text(filename):
...    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
...       text = pickle.load(f)
...    return text
... 
>>> def get_text2(filename):
...    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
...       return pickle.load(f)
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(get_text)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (open)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (filename)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('rb')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
              8 SETUP_WITH              16 (to 26)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (f)

  3          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (pickle)
             14 LOAD_METHOD              2 (load)
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
             18 CALL_METHOD              1
             20 STORE_FAST               2 (text)
             22 POP_BLOCK
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
        >>   26 WITH_CLEANUP_START
             28 WITH_CLEANUP_FINISH
             30 END_FINALLY

  4          32 LOAD_FAST                2 (text)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(get_text2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (open)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (filename)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('rb')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
              8 SETUP_WITH              12 (to 22)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (f)

  3          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (pickle)
             14 LOAD_METHOD              2 (load)
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
             18 CALL_METHOD              1
             20 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   22 WITH_CLEANUP_START
             24 WITH_CLEANUP_FINISH
             26 END_FINALLY
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `get_text2` version which returns right away avoids the `STORE_FAST`, `POP_BLOCK` and `LOAD_FAST` instructions -- but I agree the cost is probably negligible.

I think in many cases returning right away results in shorter cleaner code as well.

Comment: If you care about performance in small cases like these, Nuitka and Cython can compile and optimize pure-python code to be faster.